# socket io based Application

Tags: node.js, socket.io, kue

I am Planning an implementation of a file processing web app . The idea is to have a 
queuing mechanism where user uploads file which can be  queued  and Worker Nodejs process can pick up unprocessed records from the queue.

for the queue part I came across https://github.com/Automattic/kue . Having read the documentation I kind of understand that the  queue object  kicks-off processes

My first question is :
Do they have a way whereby another workker process can 'Pick' to process that entry  itself , instead of the queue itself initiating process?Or can i assign each job to target worker process

My second question is: assuming each worker process gets one job at a time assigned to it. and a socket endpoint wants to send progress notification to whoever uploaded that file  to the web server, Can socket.io emit message to particular IP? I understand that each client(browser ) have to connect to the socket server to start receiving messages.  But in my case Worker process are planned to pick entries from Queue .   Is is feasible to initiate a socket.io connection from server side...instead of browser initiating it .?

Hoping to get some idea . as I havent coded much for Multiple instances of nodejs  worker process.

here is a illustration of what i mean basically [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWubA.jpg)